# Что не так с bash_profile и почему появляется ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

недавно пытался запустить некую программу на Python 3.6 и возникла ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 11.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 307, in <module>
    sys.exit( main(sys.argv) )
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 11.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 166, in main
    _fixencoding()
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 11.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 148, in _fixencoding
    codeset = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 568, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 495, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 11.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 307, in <module>
    sys.exit( main(sys.argv) )
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 11.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 166, in main
    _fixencoding()
  File "/Applications/Komodo IDE 11.app/Contents/SharedSupport/dbgp/bin/py3_dbgp", line 148, in _fixencoding
    codeset = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 568, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 495, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

После чего с помощью терминала зашел в ~/.bash_profile и по указаниям добавил строки (.bash_profile тогда был абсолютно пустым):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

и ошибка так и осталась. Помогите пожалуйста исправить!

Comment: Вы после этого перезапустили терминал, чтобы .bash_profile запустился? Или выполняли его ручками: . $HOME/.bash_profile

Comment: заходил через nano ~/.bash_profile. Терминал перезапускал.